# Get MD5 Hash with Active Storage Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Before updating to Rails 5.2 I created my MD5 Hashes from Paperclip images this way: `json.image_md5 Digest::MD5.file(monument.image.path(:mobile)).hexdigest`

Now with Active Storage how can I do the same? I've tried already:

```
json.image_md5 Digest::MD5.file(url_for(monument.cover_image)).hexdigest
json.image_md5 Digest::MD5.file(rails_blob_path(monument.cover_image)).hexdigest
json.image_md5 Digest::MD5.file(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(monument.cover_image, only_path: true)).hexdigest
```

But with no success. I'm getting an error for `No such file or directory`.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Active Storage computes a Base64-encoded MD5 digest of your file, available via `monument.cover_image.checksum`.